# UIPageControl does not appear in ViewDidLoad

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ios5, ios6

How is that when I call:

`UIPageControl *pageControl = [[UIPageControl alloc] init];`
`pageControl.frame = CGRectMake(110,5,100,100); 

pageControl.numberOfPages = 2; 

pageControl.currentPage = 0; 

[self.view addSubview:pageControl];`

Inside the `ViewDidLoad` method, the `UIPageControl` does not appear?
Yet, when I call it in the `viewWillAppear` method, the page control appears?
The problem is that I don't want to have my view appear many times and have a new pagecontrol allocated and initialized each time!

Comment: are you adding any other views on to self.view after viewDidLoad? could be possible that its being overlaid by an another view?

Comment: When you put this in you viewDidLoad method, are you doing it after you call [super viewDidLoad] ?

Comment: If you are using tabBar controller then please share its code..

Comment: and how are you redirect to your view where you want to your pageController

Comment: Use loadView method or awakeFromNib to add your custom views.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ultimately, I just created my own UIPageControl as an object part of the class, retained it and initialized it in the viewDidAppear method!

This method is cleaner and doesn't waste memory!

Answer (score 0):

ViewDidLoad is called when class is loaded but view is not initialized yet. If you are doing anything with view then you should do afterward.

Best method is to move to your code to..

-(void)viewDidLayoutSubviews;

And good thing is that it will be called as soon your view is added and only Once.

Cheers.